# Passing id value from controller to html page - Spring/Java

Tags: java, spring

I am building page with spring boot that will list school classes. When clicking on one class it will lead you to details page of that particular class.

So I did next:

Classes.java

```
public class Classes {

    private String class_id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int max_numb_students;
    private int min_numb_students;


    public String getId() {
        return class_id;
    }
    public void setId(String class_id) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getMax_numb_students() {
        return max_numb_students;
    }
    public void setMax_numb_students(int max_numb_students) {
        this.max_numb_students = max_numb_students;
    }
    public int getMin_numb_students() {
        return min_numb_students;
    }
    public void setMin_numb_students(int min_numb_students) {
        this.min_numb_students = min_numb_students;
    }

}
```

This is my model.

ClassesDao.java

```
public class ClassesDao {

    private List<Classes> classesList;

    public List<Classes> getClassesList(){

        Classes classes1 = new Classes();
        Classes classes2 = new Classes();
        Classes classes3 = new Classes();

        classes1.setId("p1");
        classes1.setName("Programming in Java");
        classes1.setDescription("Learn Java");
        classes1.setMax_numb_students(20);
        classes1.setMin_numb_students(5);

        classes2.setId("c2");
        classes2.setName("Programming in Pho");
        classes2.setDescription("Learn Php");
        classes2.setMax_numb_students(20);
        classes2.setMin_numb_students(5);

        classes3.setId("d3");
        classes3.setName("ING");
        classes3.setDescription("ing");
        classes3.setMax_numb_students(20);
        classes3.setMin_numb_students(5);

        classesList = new ArrayList<Classes>();
        classesList.add(classes1);
        classesList.add(classes2);
        classesList.add(classes3);

        return classesList;
    }

    public Classes getClassesById(String class_id) throws IOException{
        for(Classes classes : getClassesList()){
            if(classes.getId().equals(class_id)){
                return classes;
            }
        }

        throw new IOException("No product found");
    }
}
```

Table.html

```
<tr th:each="classes : ${classes}">
<td th:text="${classes.name}"></td>
<td th:text="${classes.description}"></td>
<td><a href="/viewClass/${classes.class_id}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a></td>
</tr>
```

Here is link to details page.

And controller

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping("/viewClass/{class_id}")
    public String viewClass(@PathVariable String class_id, Model model) throws IOException{
        Classes classes = classesdao.getClassesById(class_id);
        model.addAttribute(classes);
        return "viewClass";
    }
```

I can't get right id to be displayed. When I hover over link I get this

[image]

So I guess I didn't pass id correctly but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change @PathVariable to @PathVariable(name="class_id")

Answer (score 0):

Remove this :

```
 public String getId() {
        return class_id;
    }
    public void setId(String class_id) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
    }
```

Add this :

```
  public String getClass_id() {
        return class_id;
    }

    public void setClass_id(String class_id) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode URL

First add spring tag library to your html file as follows :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
```

Then encode URL

```
<spring:url value="/viewClass/${classes.class_id}" var="url" htmlEscape="true"/>
 <a href="${url}">...</a>
```

Comment: isn't this for jsp? I am using html pages

Comment: I am not sure, but I think it is not only for JSP.